# if instanceof Object with special chars

Tags: javascript, node.js, special-characters, instanceof

I am trying to figure out how to check if an object is an instance of `objectwith.inthename` but the `.` is causing issues saying that `objectwith` is not defined.

```
if (myvar instanceof objectwith.inthename) { ... }
```

If I try and use `'objectwith.inthename'` as a string, then I get an error that the string is not an object.

The object is not defined in my script but is returned from a response using a  required package

Comment: Can you use any class from that package in any other way, e.g. `new objectwith.inthename()`…?

Comment: please show the definition of  `objectwith.inthename`

Comment: It works for me, but the referenced type _must_ be a constructor `Function`.

Comment: How do you even create an instance of a constructor like that ? something like `new window['objectwith.inthename']` ? just use the same syntax with `instanceof`.

Comment: @Touffy to test I did `var F = { X: function() { } }; var f = new F.X(); console.log(f instanceof F.X)`.  Hopefully the OP doesn't mean that the `.` is a literal part of the property name!

Comment: Then the dot is *not* in the object's name and your test code should work fine (it certainly does in my console).

Comment: @Alnitak I cannot show the definition as my IDE does not seem to be able to find the definition. The node package was installed globally

Comment: If it's an NPM module it would help then if you told us what module it is and what symbol it is you're trying to run `instanceof` with!

Answer (score 1):

If that is a legitimate object, then it would have to be a member of something. When you have not-variable-name-friendly variables, you can use the square bracket `[]` annotation.

What you square bracket will depend where the object is defined. Since you don't show `this`, it's probably on the `window` (in browser) or `global` (in Node.js).

```
myvar instanceof window['objectwith.inthename']
myvar instanceof global['objectwith.inthename']
```

If it is actually on `this`, then just:

```
myvar instanceof this['objectwith.inthename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Symbol.hasInstance` or `instanceof`

```
function inthename() {};

var objectwith = {};

objectwith.inthename = inthename;

var myvar = new objectwith.inthename();

console.log(myvar instanceof objectwith.inthename);

console.log(objectwith.inthename[Symbol.hasInstance](myvar));
```